# Should a REST API contain an ADMIN section and use the same OAuth 2 authorization as the rest of the API?

Tags: api, security, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm planning a web app centered on a REST API and I would like this API to be the only way to access the app, be it from my own web-site or any other tool using the API via OAuth 2 authorization.

Obviously, some critical sections should only be accessible to administrators: user deletion, billing management...

I was wondering what would be the best practice in that case:

- Should the API contain that admin section (/admin for example) which is only accessible when admin access is granted by OAuth ?
- Is that a security risk and should the administrator section be accessed differently via a different hidden secured access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the parts together and I don't think it's a security risk. I even see two different paths for the implementation:

1. Use plain OAuth2. The admin section of the API simply requires presence of "admin" scope for attached tokens, while other parts require only a "user" scope. However, you should somehow make sure that only administrator users may have a token with the "admin" scope. You may have to customize your OAuth server for this.
2. Ignore token scopes. Instead, use a special token validation to get roles of the user that granted the token.

Either way, I see no reason to seperate the admin part from the rest of the API.